# Why do I get a wrong value in SQL UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL `UPDATE` query.

When I use `SELECT`, and calculate it using PHP, outside of mySQL, everything is working great, but when I use it inside mySQL, it results in a weird number.

The query is supposed to

1. update a certain column's value (`Game.RankCube_1`)
2. update the new total average rank column (`RankCube_Total`)

This is my query:

```
UPDATE Images
SET    Game.RankCube_1 = Game.RankCube_1 + 1,
       RankCube_Total = (
                          (
                            (
                              7 * Game.RankCube_7 +
                              6 * Game.RankCube_6 +
                              5 * Game.RankCube_5 +
                              4 * Game.RankCube_4 +
                              3 * Game.RankCube_3 +
                              2 * Game.RankCube_2 +
                              1 * (Game.RankCube_1 + 1)
                             ) / (
                               Game.RankCube_7 +
                               Game.RankCube_6 +
                               Game.RankCube_5 +
                               Game.RankCube_4 +
                               Game.RankCube_3 +
                               Game.RankCube_2 +
                               Game.RankCube_1
                             )
                           ) * 100 / 7
                         )
WHERE  Game.Index = '2' AND Game.UserIndex = '1'
```

The total average comes out weird, but it's not a math issue because in php it is working and I just want to make the code work faster so I'm doing it inside the query instead of doing it inside the php.

Edit:

Those are the values for a certain scenario:

```
RankCube_7  = 1
RankCube_6  = 0
RankCube_5  = 0
RankCube_4  = 0
RankCube_3  = 0
RankCube_2  = 0
RankCube_1  = 0
```

This scenario should result in 100
But The RankCube_Total result I'm getting is 200

the math formula is simple:

```
(
7*amountOfLikesInCol7 + 
6*amountOfLikesInCol6 + 
5*amountOfLikesInCol5 + 
4*amountOfLikesInCol4 + 
3*amountOfLikesInCol3 + 
2*amountOfLikesInCol2 + 
1*amountOfLikesInCol1
) 
/ 
(
amountOfLikesInCol7+
amountOfLikesInCol6+
amountOfLikesInCol5+
amountOfLikesInCol4+
amountOfLikesInCol3+
amountOfLikesInCol2+
amountOfLikesInCol1
)
```

and to go by %, I multiple it by 100 and divide it by 7

- It is the same formula as the five stars formula in websites like Amazon and such

Comment: show us some output and please edit your query (not one-liner)

Comment: Yes, show us a row with the seven values, the result you get and the result you expect, please.

Comment: editing currently

Comment: RankCube_7  = 1
RankCube_6  = 0
RankCube_5  = 0
RankCube_4  = 0
RankCube_3  = 0
RankCube_2  = 0
RankCube_1  = 0

This scenario should result in 100  
But The RankCube_Total result Im getting is 200

the math is simple:
(7*amountOfLikesInCol7 + 6*amountOfLikesInCol7 + 5*amountOfLikesInCol5 + 4*amountOfLikesInCol4 + 3*amountOfLikesInCol3 + 2*amountOfLikesInCol2+ 1*amountOfLikesInCol1) / (amountOfLikesInCol7+amountOfLikesInCol6+amountOfLikesInCol5+amountOfLikesInCol4+amountOfLikesInCol3+amountOfLikesInCol2+amountOfLikesInCol1)

and to go by %, I multiple it by 100 and divide it by 7

Answer (score 1):

**The order of the variables in mySQL UPDATE query, matters!**

if you use the same var inside an UPDATE query string more than once, and you change it in the beginning of the query, its value wont be the same when the processor will get to its next appearance in the query.

my mistake was that I was treating a certain var through my SQL string as if it had the same value through it. BUT it changed its value through the processing of the process! as the query goes.

first I updated this var

```
Game.RankCube_1 = Game.RankCube_1 + 1
```

and while the SQL UPDATE command runs within mySQL, it updates the vars one after the other.
SO, after this var was updated (+1), the second var:

```
RankCube_Total =...
```

was suppose to treat the first var as if it is already updated.
But I treated it as if it still contains the value that it has before the

```
Game.RankCube_1 = Game.RankCube_1 + 1
```

changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to change the value of "Game.RankCube_1" when you are dividing, its still refer the old value

```
UPDATE Images SET Game.RankCube_1 = Game.RankCube_1+1, RankCube_Total = (((7*Game.RankCube_7  + 6*Game.RankCube_6  + 5*Game.RankCube_5  + 4*Game.RankCube_4  + 3*Game.RankCube_3  + 2*Game.RankCube_2  + 1*(Game.RankCube_1+1) ) / (Game.RankCube_7 + Game.RankCube_6 + Game.RankCube_5 + Game.RankCube_4 + Game.RankCube_3 + Game.RankCube_2 + Game.RankCube_1+1))*100/7) WHERE Game.Index = '2' AND Game.UserIndex = '1'
```

Comment: Thank you! that was true. it was not the major solution though. after the first var was updated, the rest of the sql string was not accurate anymore. it changes vars step by step so if you refer a certain var more than once in the query string, it will not be the same (as it was when the procedure started working), when it will get to it again.